# Phonegap/cordova-cli specify config.xml when creating app

Tags: cordova, configuration, phonegap, phonegap-cli, cordova-cli

First of all I have:

- /www folder which contains all my Files for the App
- config.xml which has all the information about the platforms, plugins etc.

With these I can use the phonegap build cloud to build my project online, awesome!

**But** weird it becomes when I want to build it locally.

There I need to use phonegap create command to create the folder structure with all the prepared files to build the apk.

The phonegap create command builds out of templates like the hello-world template.

Basicly it is required to completely reconfigure the app out of that template.

- Why isn't there a possibility to use my own config.xml when using the phonegap create command?
- Is there a "meant to be" way to do this?

I untuitivly would write a script to copy the relevant files, but I believe that won't work because there are other files carrying configuration information and there is said to be a package.json which 
 overwrites the config.xml.(Even though I cannot really find the package.json just the package-lock.json ^^)

Comment: It is possible, just make blank app with phonegap desktop aplication.. Change config.xml as you want

Comment: I use the command line interface and I would like to automate the setup of exactly (that*) project locally similarly as it is done on the phonegap build cloud.

*all projects which are defined by the combination of config.xml and the files in the www/ folder